# Cannot implicit convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<char>'to'string

Tags: c#

I'm wondering what's wrong with my code:

```
var trimmed = RemoveFromStart(Slb, new String[]{ "ab", "Ac", "Accep", "Acces", "Accessible", "AccessibleE" });

var uniqueItems = trimmed.Distinct();

rtb.SelectedText = uniqueItems;
```

Error pointing "uniqueItems".

```
//Replacing Parameter:
        public string RemoveFromStart(string s, IEnumerable<string> strings)
        {
        foreach (var x in strings.Where(s.StartsWith))
        {
            return s.Remove(0, x.Length);
        }
         return s;
        }
```

I just want every strings to be unique like "Accep" will still exist even "Ac" was the shortest string.

How can I do that?

Comment: What is the signature of `RemoveFromStart` method? What does it returns?

Comment: parameter added sir .

Answer (score 3):

An `IEnumerable<Char>` is not a `string`, so if you need one you can use the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttyxaek9.aspx):

```
rtb.SelectedText = new String(uniqueItems.ToArray());
```

If you want to find the first matching string in your abbreviation-list:

```
var abbreviations = new String[] { "ab", "Ac", "Accep", "Acces", "Accessible", "AccessibleE" };
string abbr = abbreviations.FirstOrDefault(a => Slb.StartsWith(a));
rtb.SelectedText = abbr ?? Slb;
```

Comment: sir i cant understand its output but when i type Accep, instead of AcceptRejectRule was the output it appears: AcceceptRjul ... i want all string inside unique ...

Comment: @user2234790: Sorry, but i must admit that it's still not clear. Maybe it would help if you'd show us an input string and a desired output. You say you want all strings to be unique, but there is only one string. I assume the `string[]` is fixed, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Since [`Enumerable.Distinct()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx) method returns`IEnumerable<T>` (in this case `IEnumerable<Char>`) which is not clearly a `string`, you can use it with `char[]` constructor to initialize it.

```
rtb.SelectedText = new String(uniqueItems.ToArray());
```

> *Initializes a new instance of the String class to the value indicated
>   by an array of Unicode characters.*

Answer (score 1):

Did you check what `Distinct` returns in this case its `IEnumerable<char>` so you will have to convert the same to a string using the constructor overloads of `char[]`

so you can do a `new string(trimmed.Distinct().ToArray())` and assign it to SelectedText which is expecting a string

Comment: sir i cant understand its output but when i type Accep, instead of AcceptRejectRule was the output it appears: AcceceptRjul ... i want all string inside unique ...

Comment: how to do that? inside my strings?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert it to string. It will not convert automatically.

```
var uniqueItems = trimmed.Distinct();
rtb.SelectedText = new string(uniqueItems);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a `string` and using `Distinct()` to get the unique characters, this returns as an `IEnumerable<char>`. Tou need to convert it back into a `string` somehow, here is one method:

```
rtb.SelectedText = string.Join(string.Empty, uniqueItems);
```